# How to limit overall union in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, union

I have these nodes:

1. `user{user_id}: users`
2. `thread{thread_id, post_date} : posts`
3. `tag_id{tag_id}: the tag of the post`

And these relationships:

1. `(user) - [: FOLLOWED] -> (tag)` // the user follows the tag
2. `(thread) - [: BELONG_TO] -> (tag)` // the post belongs to tag
3. `(user) - [: READ{read_date}] -> (thread)` // user reads the post
4. `(user) - [: BEING_REPLIED{post_date}] -> (thread)` // the user is given a reply by another user to his / her comment in a post
5. `(user) - [: BEING_MENTIONED{post_date}] -> (thread)` // the user is given a mention by another user comment in a post

I want to get 10 posts that the user is replied or mentioned by another user, then to the posts that belong to tag the user follows but the user has not read to display in each user's feed, I use multiple unions in the query but cannot limit to the total, the resulting form is limited to the last union
I wrote cypher as follows:

```
MATCH (u:User {user_id:3})-[rp:BEING_REPLIED]->(th:Thread)<-[r:READ]-(u:User {user_id:3})
WHERE rp.post_date> r.read_date
return u.user_id as user_id,th.thread_id as thread_id,
duration.inDays(datetime(),datetime(rp.post_date)).days*10 + 1000000 AS point
UNION ALL

MATCH (u:User {user_id:3})-[m:BEING_MENTIONED]->(th:Thread)<-[r:READ]-(u:User {user_id:3})
WHERE m.post_date> r.read_date
return u.user_id as user_id,th.thread_id as thread_id,
duration.inDays(datetime(),datetime(m.post_date)).days*10 + 1000000 AS point
UNION ALL

MATCH (u:User {user_id:3})-[m:BEING_MENTIONED]->(th:Thread)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((u)-[:READ]->(th))
return u.user_id as user_id,th.thread_id as thread_id,
duration.inDays(datetime(),datetime(m.post_date)).days*10 + 1000000 AS point

MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]->(th)
WHERE u.user_id = 3 AND NOT EXISTS((u)-[]->(th))
WITH u.user_id AS user_id, th.thread_id AS thread_id,
(0.5*th.like_count + 0.3*th.comment_count + 0.005*th.view_count
+ duration.inDays(datetime(),datetime(th.published_date)).days*100) AS point
ORDER BY point desc
RETURN DISTINCT user_id, thread_id, point
UNION
MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]->(th)
WHERE u.user_id = 3 AND NOT EXISTS((u)-[]->(th))
AND NOT th.rating_total  IS NULL
WITH u.user_id AS user_id, th.thread_id AS thread_id,
(duration.inDays(datetime(),datetime(th.published_date)).days*150 + 30*th.rating_total) AS point
ORDER BY point desc, th.published_date desc
RETURN DISTINCT user_id, thread_id, point
LIMIT 10
```

How can i set this query limit overall?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need subqueries for this, you should be using Neo4j 4.0.x or later, this allows you to perform [post-UNION processing](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/)

Usage of UNION ALL in the subquery, with the LIMIT 10 outside of it, should allow you to get what you want.